# Does the native VPN client support IKEv1 as of Android 12?

Tags: vpn, android-12

Is there any official documentation on what IPSec key exchange types are
supported by the native Android 12 IPSec client (Racoon)? Specifically I’m
interested in whether IKEv1 still works.

I’m asking this because I’m thrown off by [a paragraph on the OpenWRT wiki](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/strongswan/roadwarrior#for_android_clients)
which seems to indicate that as of v12, only IKEv2 modes are supported,
killing off ISAKMP which has worked until v11. After spending some time
searching for an official announcement or even just a feature list I came up
empty handed.

The screenshot on this Github issue: https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN/issues/1373
appears to confirm the removal of IKEv1 in v12.

Comment: This was mentioned in passing on the official [Android Developer - IPsec/IKEv2 Library](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/ipsec): "*The module also enables **deprecation and replacement of the racoon-based IKEv1 VPN library** used as the default built-in VPN client in Android 10 and lower.*" (emphasis added), though looks like it's started to be enforced since Android 12 Beta 2 (ref: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/android_beta/comments/ny37vy/android_12_vpn_options_limited/), [GitHub - 
SoftEtherVPN](https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN/issues/1373)).

Comment: @AndrewT.: Yes I’m aware of that document but seeing that Android 11 still had support for IKEv1 I’m uncertain whether Google has already advanced past the deprecation phase into replacement of Racoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**.

[This commit added an exception that is thrown when the user
tries to initiate an IKEv1 connection.](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/3eb2a54e31b08d8cc1e1cdd385c8a96fd8e1c3e6)
The [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/189808606) with the id given in the commit message is non-public
so presumably this change was motivated not by technical but
policy considerations.